# Wrong ClientRect height when image inside targeted element

Tags: javascript

I have simple html:

```
<a href='#' id='target'>
  <img src='https://sftextures.com/texture/6485/0/6487/metal-dots-very-dark-grey-black-solid-material-seamless-texture-256x256.jpg'/>
</a>
```

I want to get the height of the #target element which should basically copy the image:

```
let target = document.getElementById('target');
let height = target.getBoundingClientRect().height;
// result 18px, image size is 256px
```

Why the target a link element does not copy the height of the child? Let's say my site has thousands of elements and I can't identify children. How could I get correct height in similar cases where it does not match the real height?

https://jsfiddle.net/b2y8gtLx/

Comment: because `<a>` is not a block element, so browser don't care about his real size

Comment: Thanks @Mrj but if I do a:focus {outline: 1px solid border} then the css can wrap the element correctly so how come there is no such function in javascript without changing the styles?

Comment: ?? 2 solutions :
1- add `target.style.display = 'inline-block';` to your js code,
2- make a proposal to the W3C with solids arguments and wait a couple of years for this implementation

Answer (score 1):

If you have more elements, try setting a `<div>` as parent. Should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

let height = target.offsetHeight.
Please try it. It is working

Comment: `offsetWidth` will take `<a/>` width not height of `<a/>`, but OP's question is height not width

Answer (score 0):

with making display to 'inline-block'

```js
target.onclick = function ()  // just to take care of image loading delay
{ 
  target.style.display = 'inline-block';

  targetHeight.textContent = `parent height: ${target.getBoundingClientRect().height} px `;
  image_Height.textContent = `img height: ${ImgInsideA.getBoundingClientRect().height} px `;

  target.style.display = null;

  console.log( target.getBoundingClientRect().height );
}
```

```html
<a href='#' id='target'>
  <img id="ImgInsideA"
    src='https://sftextures.com/texture/6485/0/6487/metal-dots-very-dark-grey-black-solid-material-seamless-texture-256x256.jpg' />
</a>

<div id='targetHeight'> -- </div>
<div id='image_Height'> -- </div>
```